# Is removing the `${jndi:` string a mitigation of the log4j security issue?

Tags: threat-mitigation, log4shell

Recently, the log4j issue got a lot of attention. I run a chatbot web app that is not based on the JAVA stack. However, there is a backend component that analyzes the chatbot user input which is based on JAVA. I wonder to mitigate the log4j issue, whether scanning the text input as a pre-processing in the backend and removing all the references of `${jndi:` is a solution to mitigate the security issue?

Comment: Isn't this question just a more specific case of [Can one protect from the Log4j exp by sanitizing the parameters](/q/257921/129883)?

Comment: There are too much ways the attack string can look like and the simple string match will only match the simple ones.